# DPDK Error: "Cause: No Ethernet ports - bye"

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, dpdk

The title is the last line of an error while trying to run a sample application of dpdk, named l2fwd. When I run the app by `./build/l2fwd -l 0-3 -n 4 -- -q 8 -p ffff` but at last lines this error occurs:

> EAL: Error - exiting with code: 1
>
> Cause: No Ethernet ports - bye

According to dpdk documentation before running app I must execute a command: `modprobe ixgbe max_vfs=2,2`

I also have a problem with this command, but I'm not sure this is the main reason of failing app execution.

Error of modprobe command relates to ixgbe driver which I can't install it. The error after `make` of ixgbe is

> cc1: error: code model kernel does not support PIC mode
>
> Makefile:197: *** *** Aborting the build. *** This driver is not supported on kernel versions older than 2.4.0.  Stop.

Comment: Can you add more info on what is you scenario? Hypervisor, NIC model, gcc version, etc.
Are you trying to use SR-IOV? Please also show the output of 
'dpdk_folder/usertools/dpdk-devbind.py --status'

Answer (score 0):

To you a NIC with DPDK we need to bind it to UIO or VFIO driver.

Please have a look at [Binding and Unbinding Network Ports to/from the Kernel Modules](https://doc.dpdk.org/guides/linux_gsg/linux_drivers.html#binding-and-unbinding-network-ports-to-from-the-kernel-modules) in DPDK's getting started guide.